# when i run this code it returns the profit made for each individual item. How can I get it to calculate the total profit with what I have so far:

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find a way to calculate the total profit made based on a dictionary of items and three values the cost, sell price, and inventory. When I run the code, it returns two values (the profit for each individual item). How can I then get the total profit?

PS- I am very new to coding so any tips would be much appreciated

```
shop_items= {
    "banana":(23.50,26.50,100),
     "egg":(13,17,12)
     }

for item in shop_items:
    shop_item=shop_items[item][0]
    cost_item=shop_items[item][1]
    shop_inventory=shop_items[item][2]
    total_cost=shop_inventory*shop_item
    total_sale= shop_inventory*cost_item
    print(total_sale-total_cost)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and Programming! We do things a bit differently here than a classroom, and would like to see what you've already done. If you could please add a code sample that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use `shop_items.items()` to iterate over the dictionary in a one-liner.

```
>>> shop_items= {
...     "banana":(23.50,26.50,100),
...      "egg":(13,17,12)
...      }
>>> sum([(i[1] - i[0]) * i[2] for k,i in shop_items.items()])
348.0
```

This uses a list comprehension to put the total profit on each product type in a list, then `sum` to add the profits together. `k` is the dictionary key `('banana', 'egg')` which are not needed for the calculation. `i` is the value of the each of the elements of the dictionary.

Instead of a list comprehension, you could continue to use a `for` loop,

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for k, i in shop_items.items():
...     total += (i[1] - i[0]) * i[2]
```

The use of `items()` might be a bit clearer here. Each iteration of the loop fetches both the key and value from `shop_items`. So the first time it would fetch `k = 'banana'` and `i = (23.50, 26.50, 100)`. Then you can refer to the values just with `i` plus the index. If you put the statement `print(k)` inside the `for` loop you will see it operating on 1 element at a time.